A long-form mathematics books tetris questions
I am currently trying to solve the problem 1.4 from the book Proofs: A long-form mathematics textbook. This problem is about tetris, and it requires to prove that it is impossible to cover a 4x5 chess board with one (and only one) of each of the tetris shapes (allow the possible rotations and symmetric parts, but only one for each of the parts).
To solve this issue I thought about some things that could help to solve it, including:

Each part has some constraints on which possible parts are allowed after that one is put.
Since the solution is statics (no movement of parts is required), the sequence in which the parts are put into the board should not affect the plausibility of a solution.
There are some movements/parts that are blocked in each of the right-left up-down axis after each part has been put into the board.


There are seven tetrominos. Are you allowed to choose any five out of the seven?

Try using black and white squares as used at the end of this article

@ksimple trying to be accurate as I can, if you have the square, the line, the T, the S, the symmetric S, the L, and the symmetric L, you need to use the square, the line, the T, one of the S's and o one of the L's.

Another hint is, think about where the line can go and why this is an issue.

The standard chessboard coloring (which I believe is what Wasu was first going for) works directly. What have you tried in that regard?

Consider the black and white squares on the chessboard. If you draw it out, you can see that there are an equal number of both- 10 white squares and 10 black squares.
Looking at each of the tetris shapes, we notice that all of them except for the "T" shape cover an equal number of black squares and white squares. But the "T" shape covers either three black squares and one white square or three white squares and one black square. So any cover which involves the "T" shape will cover an unequal number of black squares and white squares- and therefore it can't be a valid cover.

